# Scrapy pipeline django sqlite3 database error on save

Tags: django, scrapy

It seems that Scrapy can't see database because item.save() return error. `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: myapp_myitem` It's not problem with Django model because I can add/edit it from Django admin without errors.

**items.py**

```
from scrapy.contrib.djangoitem import DjangoItem
from myapp.models import Myitem

class MyitemItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Myitem
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from myapp.models import Myitem
from items.models import License, Category, Special

class MyitemPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
    item.save()
    return item
```

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapyproject.pipelines.MyitemPipeline':1000,
}

import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_project')

import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings.local'
```

**my_django_project/settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'db/local_db',
    'USER': 'me',

}
```

Comment: may be you forgot to run syncdb ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer to my question after I fix the problem because it's trivial problem which take from me all day. Maybe it can be useful to someone.

After I change `NAME` of database to absolute path to the sqlite3 database Scrapy was store data successfuly. So Scrapy need absolue path to the sqlite3 database and changing name to absolute path to the db will not affect Django functionality.